# Vagrant editing?

Tags: macos, file, vagrant

How can I edit files that are in my Vagrant box *after* I create them. I have files in my `/var/www/` that are in the box but not on my local machines file system. I'm not sure if synced folders does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the `/var/www/` directory to be synced from&to your host. For example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www"    
  # ...
end
```

Or you can `vagrant ssh` into the VM and edit them from there. But note that all the modifications are lost when the box is destroyed.